# Failed to update from GitHub

Tags: xcode, github, alamofire, repo

I’m trying to create an app in Xcode but all of a sudden I run into this error:

> Failed to update from github"

[image: Error Screenshot]

I have updated the Access token but that didn't work. I’m not sure even where to look. Is it maybe a GitHub error or is it in my code?

I’m hoping that I can successfully build and run a test for the app. But the GitHub repo does not contain the JSON Swift code it seems.